# Saving and restoring neural network weights in production

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, neural-network, save, production

I am currently building a backend that uses a neural network.
I need to save the weights (which may be 2 dimensional, 3 dimensional or 4 dimensional), and restore them. 
I am currently using heroku, and thus need to save them either to PostgreSQL, or to a S3 bucket and retrieve it everytime the system boots.

What is the go-to solution for storing and restoring weights for ML applications in production, where the weights may be multiple hundred-thousand entries and the matrix can be well over 100mb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do store neural network weights over S3 and it works pretty good.

Also we update those weights as we train with new data and update to s3. The live system checks for modified s3 object and update the weights / neural network based on the stored data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html

> aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket --key object.h5

You can also enable accelerated endpoint for speed. This is needed if you are downloading the object over the internet.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: did you ever have to download anything that was about 1GB, and do you know if this is feasible in production?

Comment: It is very much feasible in production. Handle errors correct and retry when needed. 1 GB is nothing for S3. If you want to optimize for speed, you split them as separate object and download them parallely and join them on client side. You can also read partial data from object, splitting and joining them is very easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: Using Postgres and the Postgres datatype ARRAY, it is also possible to store large matrices for production.